# Broken Ribbon - everything is disappearing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ribbon

I am trying to use a ribbon in my application.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application-Cs) on CodeProject using Visual Studio 2012.

Everything works until I compile the project.

If I close Form design then Visual Studio gives me this error:

> There is no stack trace or error line information available for this
>   error

Next, all panels and tabs from ribbon disappear. It Doesn´t matter if I save the solution or when I close a Form.

I try it with sample from CodeProject and I put it in my project, but both ended with this error.

Is there some possibility to clear this error? Or do you know of another solution for a ribbon?

Comment: Does sample project from codeproject works well?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace please?

Comment: @IanO'Brien: You so funny.

Comment: @Dan-o whoops I missed that! Sometimes if I 1) clean the solution 2) close the solution 3) open the solution 4) do a full rebuild - things like this fix themselves. Have you tried that?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for people to help, we need something to work with. Anton's comment is a good starting place, can the base project work for you, if it does, then start making changes and see if you can find what causes your project to break.